# Is it possible change the question example in the about page?

Tags: discusión, soporte, petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado

¿Es posible cambiar la pregunta de ejemplo en:

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/about

> What is Spanish for "John Doe" in Puerto Rico?

La pregunta de ejemplo que está puesta en la página [About](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/about) debería ser distinta a la actual, nosotros no deberíamos mostrar ese tipo de preguntas como guía o referencia para los nuevos visitantes al sitio.

Yo me inclino por preguntas como esta por poner un ejemplo:

[Uso invertido de palabras cariñosas e insultos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/uso-invertido-de-palabras-carinosas-e-insultos)

Por favor comenten si estan de acuerdo y cual sería su propuesta.

---

Is it possible change the question example in the about page?

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/about

> What is Spanish for "John Doe" in Puerto Rico?

The question example in the [About](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/about) page should be something different to "phrasebook Spanish". We shouldn't show that kind of question as a guide to the new users and or be the 1st impression. I thought.

I propose something like:

[Uso invertido de palabras cariñosas e insultos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/uso-invertido-de-palabras-carinosas-e-insultos)

Please propose a question for the [About](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/about) page or share your thoughts about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but the choices are [somewhat limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/1438).  As of today, these questions are available:

1. [What is Spanish for "John Doe" in Puerto Rico?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/what-is-spanish-for-john-doe-in-puerto-rico)
2. [Alternativas a "irretrasable"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/alternativas-a-irretrasable)
3. [¿Se usa 'guácala' fuera de México?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/se-usa-guacala-fuera-de-mexico)
4. [What is the difference between "ser cierto" and "ser verdad"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/what-is-the-difference-between-ser-cierto-and-ser-verdad)
5. [Translation of "by the way"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/translation-of-by-the-way)
6. [What is the longest word in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2079/what-is-the-longest-word-in-spanish)
7. [Rules of style for Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/rules-of-style-for-spanish)
8. [What's the meaning of "Y yo voy y me lo creo"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/whats-the-meaning-of-y-yo-voy-y-me-lo-creo)
9. [Why isn't "good morning" "buenas mañanas"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/918/why-isnt-good-morning-buenas-mananas)
10. [Translation of "contact info"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/505/translation-of-contact-info)
11. [How prevalent is the phrase "qué padre"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-prevalent-is-the-phrase-que-padre)
12. ['vos' vs 'tú' usage by country](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25/vos-vs-tu-usage-by-country)
13. [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre tú, usted y vos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/7/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-tu-usted-y-vos)

If any of these questions look better than the current question, feel free to make you case in another answer.  Then ping me or a moderator to look into changing it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

From that list my first choice would be:

[Alternativas a “irretrasable”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/alternativas-a-irretrasable)

There are only 3 question in spanish, and I think this is the most suitable for the [about](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/about) page

Comment: @jonEricson, here you have my option. thanks

Comment: That seems good to me.  I've changed it for now.